# Only Authorize back orders but Authorize and Capture all other orders

Tags: magento-enterprise, authorize.net, backorder

I want to enable back orders but I want to only Authorize back orders but Authorize and Capture all other orders.

**Is this possible to do? We are using Authorize.net and Magento Enterprise 1.12.02**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able to do that by default in Magento Enterprise as the Authorize.net payment method does not allow for partial payments for specific products / rules, etc.

I do know that there are a couple of partial payment modules out there that will help achieve what you need done, like [www.milople.com/magento-extensions/partial-payment.html](http://www.milople.com/magento-extensions/partial-payment.html)

And there are many others on Magento connect or simple Google

Comment: I am not sure how a partial payment is going to achieve this.  We want to take the back order, the in a week or how ever long it takes to fulfill the order then we would capture the funds at that time instead of when the order is placed on the website.

Comment: Well, i said partial payments as it allows to split the order on a back order item and use a separate payment method which is set to just auth rather than auth capture. In default Magento, it does not allow for you to choose how the payment module will work for 2 different products or work on some sort of rule basis. Having said that, the easiest way to achiev this then is to do some custom work, an observer in the payment model that that will check if its a back order and set payment flow to auth only, where all other would follow auth and capture. Then Admin would need to capture payment.

Comment: Never thought about writing an observer to change to auth only instead of auth and capture.  That might just work.

Comment: Ye, let me know if you need any help and ill see if i can cook up something :)